# Why does the TinyMCE server-side handler example in PHP include a file extension check if you can't select a non-image anyway?

Tags: tinymce

Interesting.

I wanted to add logic to catch the upload of non-images. In the PHP example in the docs, they had this:

```
// Verify extension    
if (!in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($temp['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)), array("gif", "jpg", "png"))) {
  header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid extension.");
  return;
}
```

So I added something like that to my server's backside server-side JavaScript.

But it turned out not to be necessary. The image upload dialogs (either browse or drag-and-drop) somehow don't let you select anything but images.

If that's so, why does the example add that to the handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons but I'll stick to the main 2:

1. You may not want to accept all image types, perhaps you don't want users to upload .gif files because it will be ugly to see gif images in content, or perhaps your server doesn't support this type of image.
2. Using terminal commands like curl or GUI applications like [Postman](https://www.postman.com/), you can skip the normal browser upload workflow and upload whatever you like to the server. Highly dangerous as users could upload anything if you don't perform some sort of validation, they could upload a .php file for example and cause all sorts of havoc.

Comment: A followup if you don't mind. I tested with a tiff, and it properly did not upload. However the error showed was simply "upload failed." There was no mention of the error in the return `HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid extension.` Is there a way of show more info to the user about why it failed? Thanks.

Comment: You change the behaviour through the editor’s config, see https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/general-configuration-guide/upload-images/ for more details

Comment: Currently I have it successfully working using the images_upload_url option where I wrote my own backend server-side script to save the image in the desired location with a unique name and return that location so it gets set correctly in the img tag in the editor. To configure the editor does that mean instead of that I need to use the images_upload_handler option?